# Getting x from remote sources and mirroring on to a list

Tags: javascript, json, http, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have this, if with the full app it will create a post with my chosen parameters, however I am very new with vue.js, My aim is to be able to have a text file of such (or other way of storing (json etc)) the values, and then having the js script iterate through the file and display as cards, so for example in the file I would have

```
"Mark", "http://google.com", "5556", "image"
```

Or of course using json or similar, I'm up to what ever but my problem is, I don't know how to get values from a remote source and mirror it on to the document, can anyone help?, for clarity here's the snippet of code that I'm using

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword: '',
    postList: [

    new Post(
      'Name', 
      'Link', 
      'UID', 
      'Image'), 
    ]
  },
});
```

-- EDIT --

I'd like to thank the user [Justin MacArthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771218/justin-macarthur) for his quick answer, if you or anyone else doesn't mind answering another one of my painfully incompetent questions. This is the function that adds the cards in a nutshell

```
var Post = function Post(title, link, author, img) {
  _classCallCheck(this, Post);
  this.title = title;
  this.link = link;
  this.author = author;
  this.img = img;
};
```

I can now get the data from the text file, meaning I could do, and assuming I have response defined (that being the http request) it'll output the contents of the file, how would I do this for multiple cards- as, as one would guess having a new URL for each variable in each set of four in each card is not just tedious but very inefficient.

```
new Post(
  response.data, 
)
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're looking to do an AJAX request to the server and have it return the values? either as a file or programmed response.

Comment: That is correct, any method that will allow me to get the required responses and add append them to the list will be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is any of the AJAX libraries available. Vue used to promote `vue-resource` though it recently retired that support in favor of [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

You can follow the instructions on the github page to install it in your app and the usage is very simple.

```
    // Perform a Get on a file/route
axios.get(
    'url.to.resource/path', 
    {
        params: {
            ID: 12345
        }
    }
).then(
    // Successful response received
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
).catch(
    // Error returned by the server
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);

// Perform a Post on a file/route
// Posts don't need the 'params' object as the second argument is sent as the request body
axios.post(
    'url.to.resource/path', 
    {
        ID: 12345
    }
).then(
    // Successful response received
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
).catch(
    // Error returned by the server
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Obviously in the catch handler you'd have your error handing code, either an alert or message appearing on the page. In the success you could have something along the lines of `this.postList.push(new Post(response.data.name, response.data.link, response.data.uid, response.data.image));`

To make it even easier you can assign axios to the vue prototype like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

and make use of it using the local vm instance

```
this.$http.post("url", { data }).then(...);
```

EDIT:
For your multi-signature function edit it's best to use the `arguments` keyword. In Javascript the engine defines an `arguments` array containing the parameters passed to the function.

```
var Post = function Post(title, link, author, img) {
  _classCallCheck(this, Post);

  if(arguments.length == 1) {
    this.title = title.title;
    this.link = title.link;
    this.author = title.author;
    this.img = title.img;
  } else {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.author = author;
    this.img = img;
  }
};
```

Be careful not to mutate the arguments list as it's a reference list to the parameters themselves so you can overwrite your variables easily without knowing it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!, if you wouldn't mind (and don't at all feel obliged to help me anymore than you already have), would you mind helping me out just a little bit more?, if so check the edit...

Comment: @TheDoctor There's a quick edit for your other question.